# Django-paypal works in IPN simulator but not in sandbox

Tags: python, django, paypal

I have written an IPN following the django-paypal IPN tutorial, however mine does not seem to work. It works no problem on the PayPal IPN Simulator, and I receive the IPN and the code executes, however when I try to do it in Sandbox mode, the payment goes through by no response.

Views:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm

def view_that_asks_for_money(request):

    # What you want the button to do.
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": "receiver_email@example.com",
        "amount": "100.00",
        "item_name": "Product",
        "invoice": "100",
        "notify_url": "http://myip/paypal/",
        "return_url": "https://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
        "cancel_return": "https://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",
        "custom": "Upgrade all users!",  # Custom command to correlate to some function later (optional)
    }

    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "payment.html", context)

from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received

def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    category = Category(name="Got IPN")
    category.save()
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        category = Category(name="Good Buzz, complete")
        category.save()
    else:
        category = Category(name="Bad Buzz, not complete")
        category.save()


valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
invalid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

URLS:

```
etc etc etc...
    url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
    url(r'^test/$', views.view_that_asks_for_money, name='ask')
]
```

When I send my IPN to : http://myip/paypal/ it works but not through sandbox.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am having the same error :/

Comment: Can’t remember fully, but ensure you are operating fully in the prod environment. If you send a payment in live but it tries to verify in sandbox it’ll fail.